# Rails validation inclusion error 'not included in list'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, inclusion

I have a table which in a MySQL db with this model:

```
class Client< ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 255}, :presence => true
  validates :client_status, inclusion: { in: 0..2, :presence => true }
  validates :client_type, inclusion: { in: 0..2, :presence => true}
end
```

So I want the client_status and the client_type to only be numeric values between 0 and 2, here is the rspec I wrote to accommodate this:

```
describe Client do
  before do
    @client = Client.new
  end

  it "should allow name that is less than 255 characters" do
    long_char = 'a' *254
    @client.name = long_char
    @client.client_status = 0
    @client.client_type = 1
    @client.should be_valid
  end

end
```

This is a pretty simple test, I have presence true for both client_status and client_type so I must add those in the RSPEC, however running this rspec gives me this error message:

```
got errors: Value type is not included in the list, Status is not included in the list
```

I tried this, to see what the output is:

```
puts "client type is: #{@client.client_type} and status is: #{@client.client_status} ."
```

I received this output:

```
client type is: false and status is:  .
```

Note: I have changed the names of the model/rspec and some of the fields so that I do not violate my companies NDA.

Comment: How does the schema for this table look like? In particular, what are the types of client_type and client_status? Are they really integers?

Comment: try changing `inclusion: { in: 0..2, :presence => true }` to `inclusion: { in: 0..2}, :presence => true`

Comment: @Jakob S - The fields are both TINYINT

Comment: @xlembouras - I have tried this and it produces the same error

Comment: I have tried your code on a blank project, and I cannot reproduce what you've reported. The code you have posted works as you expect with Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.1, RSpec 3.1 at least.

Comment: Sounds like the attributes are set somewhere in your code automatically. Search your Client model for `client_status` and `client_type` and watch out for `before_validation` hooks. Look at potential setters, maybe even `assign_attributes` was overridden.

Comment: What does your `puts` "debug statement" output before and after the line `@client.should be_valid`, respectively?

Comment: @p11y - I was able to indeed fix the issue thanks to your comment; I realized that in the migration for the table I created the data type tinyint by specifying client_type and client_status as boolean. This was something I found online. I changed the data types to integer with another migration and this made the test pass. Not sure which post to give the answer too but seeing as you helped me realize this thank you very much p11y and everyone else who commented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In rails you need to divide validators by comma:

```
    validates :client_status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: 0..2 }
```

2. It has no sense to check presence, if you check on inclusion. So you can simplify your code by simple validation:

```
    validates :client_status, inclusion: { in: 0..2 }
```

Comment: Are client_status and client_type integer columns in db?

Comment: Yes they are both TINYINT in the db

Comment: Going to mark this as the correct answer since this is how it should be done and my solution was an issue with the data type I set in the database, should not have been tinyint but rather integer.

Comment: You should have written that answer and accepted it then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `numericality:` like this:

```
validates :client_status, numericality: { only_integer: true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 2 }, :presence => true
```

Comment: I tried this and got the error 'got errors: Client type can't be blank, Client status can't be blank' To add to this the puts statement is still showing false and ' ' respectively.